# adding data gathering to a utility app and publish it to partners?

Tags: ethics

I've been working on a utility app for a while, and when we're in the final phases the boss is asking for adding user behavior and location tracking and was explicit about publishing them to 3rd party developers to make use of them.

He seems to have set his mind about it, is there anything I can/should do about it?

Clarify: if you are an app developer who's asked to add data gathering of the app users and publishing it, is there anything you should say against it ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking here.

Comment: It depends on what your company's published privacy policy says.

Comment: I donot think that this is legal in european union without explicilty asking the user for permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with obtaining and selling some data, provided that this is legal in all applicable jurisdictions, and that you don't hide this fact. Specifically:

- During installation, but before purchase, the app should inform the user that access to GPS etc. is required. Of course a potential user will become suspicious if such functionality is required without your app offering location-dependant functionality. You can ask your boss if potentially limiting the success of your app is a good business decision.
- The privacy policy should mention that data may be shared with 3rd parties.

There are some considerations regarding good UX:

- Do not continuously transmit telemetry. This avoids incurring unexpected data fees for the user, and conserves battery.
- Do not unnecessarily run in the background, see the point about battery.
- Do not create an app that behaves like malware or spyware.

I would also like to point out that it is possible to collect interesting data without including directly or indirectly identifying information. Data like usage patterns is extremely fascinating, but creating detailed movement patterns or extracting personal information from other apps is creepy.

It is interesting that these additional requirements came up very late in the development process, and it may be interesting to find out why. If this is just a case of shifting requirements during development (without accounting for this through agile methodologies), this is just the usual headache.
If however you have reason to believe these requirements have existed for a longer time, this is more interesting. In a worst case scenario, an evil boss would have waited until the project is almost completed, so that you have a high personal investment and do not wish it to fail for something “as minor” as ethically questionable data collection.

- Determine the exact type and breadth of data collection, and evaluate it regarding legality, business concerns, user experience, and make sure the user isn't coaxed into using the app despite these data collections.

  - If there are objective issues, raise these in the context of whishing to ship the best possible product.
- Determine your personal (subjective) ethical red line which you do not whish to cross.

  - If the project is well inside your comfort zone, implement the functionality.
  - If the project is far on the other side of your red line, voice your concerns and start looking for the next job.
  - If the project is in the neighborhood of the red line, implement the project but start looking for other jobs. It is probably not worth risking temporary unemployment if this is a one-off situation.

Comment: Yeah, on its own, the requirement doesn't seem bad - but I think I'd easily get suspicious that this requirement is being asked for on a whim too late, without bringing it up with the legal department. I'd think most of the time, this would at least require a message on first-start that notifies "This app tracks some anonymous blah blah blah...OK? Yes / No"